drizzle ORM select data from table in order of newest data
I am using drizzle ORM with my Next.js & PostgreSQL
I want to get the data from the newest data to the first one (oldest)
I know orderBy() could help me ! for id of my post Iam using uuid not serial
 const allData = await db.select().from(articlesTable).orderBy(?);
this could be my answer
 const allData = (await db.select().from(articlesTable)).reverse();
but I don't want get all data because may I want to use limit(10) and just select 10 last (newest) rows of my table for that no need to get all rows from database !
And the main problem is that my database (over 8Ks of records) has no columns like created_at edited-at or even a number like serial to pass on it for orderBy

What is the name of the column that you want to order by?

To get the data in descending order of a particular column (for example columnName, you can run the following code:
const allData = await db.select().from(articlesTable).orderBy(desc(articlesTable.columnName));
You can find examples in the drizzle orm documentation here

Thanks for your reply, but the problem is that none of the columns are suitable for ordering and I want the reverse sequence of PgAdmin that you see when you execute the SELECT command. I will edit the question for more details
